# How do I encrypt a SOAP request using a public key

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, encryption, soap

In one of my application I need to invoke a web service.The web service uses OASIS standard. The conditions are as follows:

A ) The request has to be digitally signed using the private key of the user.Signature 
include key info element that contains X.509  certificate details.This is needed for 
server to validate the signer.The below elements in the SOAP request has to be signed

**Timestamp**

**UsernameToken**

**Body**

B) After signing, the request has to be encrypted using the e-Filing’s public key
Use the URI https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/WebServiceIncomeTaxPublicKey.cer to download the public key. 
The below contents are encrypted using the public key
**UsernameToken**
**Body**

```
BulkPanService Servicee = new BulkPanService();


        // Create the UsernameToken we use to sign the message
        UsernameToken userToken;
        userToken = new UsernameToken("XXXXXX", "XXXXX", PasswordOption.SendHashed);
        Servicee.SetClientCredential(userToken);

        // Adds the token to the SOAP header.
        SoapContext context = Servicee.RequestSoapContext;
        context.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 60000;
        context.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken);


        MessageSignature sig = new MessageSignature(signatureToken);
        sig.SignatureOptions = SignatureOptions.IncludeTimestamp | SignatureOptions.IncludeSoapBody;
        context.Security.Elements.Add(sig);

        BulkPanRequest request = new BulkPanRequest();
        request.uniqueRequestId = "XXXXXXXX";

        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"path");
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();
        request.dataHandler = fileBytes;

        //  First of all create an encrypting token
        X509SecurityToken encryptingToken = GetServerToken();


        // Encrypt the UsernameToken element in the SOAP header
        Servicee.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new EncryptedData(encryptingToken));

        BulkPanResponse response = new BulkPanResponse();
        response = Servicee.uploadBulkPan(request);
```

But when

```
Servicee.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new EncryptedData(encryptingToken));
```

line executes It is throwing error

> WSE527: The SecurityToken does not support data encryption.

Please anyone who knows how to invoke the webservice with the above condition, help me to sort this issue.

Comment: Hi @jayakrishna did you find the solution. can you please let me know.